# Datatables.net Server-Side pagination with Spring: How to select single row's ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, spring, datatables

I'm working on a web app with React front and Spring Boot back. I'm using datatables with server-side pagination (spring controller and all that). It works to see the table and different pages. However, now I would like to click on the row to select its ID. I tried to follow different examples from datatables, but it always returns empty. I also installed datatables.net-select-bs4 via npm, maybe I can use it somehow? Sorry I'm new to datatables.
What I have now (front):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../dataTables.min.css';

const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net-bs4');

export default class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var selected = [];
    var table = $('#paginatedTable').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"data-table-wrapper"t>',
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 5,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/map-runner/api/calculations",
            "data": function (data) {
         }},
        "columns": this.props.columns,
        "rowCallback": function(row, data) {
                if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                    $(row).addClass('selected');
                }
            }
    });

    $('#paginatedTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = $.inArray(id, selected);

        if (index === -1) {
            selected.push(id);
        } else {
            selected.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

        console.log(table.rows( { selected: true } ));

    } );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
       $('.data-table-wrapper').find('table').DataTable().destroy(true);
    }


    render() {
        return (
    <div class="container">
      <div class="starter-template">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="paginatedTable" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Date Create</th>
                            <th>Date Update</th>
                            <th>User ID</th>
                            <th>ID Type</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
               </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% but I think that if you want to use `this.id` you yave to use next property in datatable initialization:

```
rowId: 'staffId'
```

`staffId` is the name of the column that you use for set the id.

Documentation:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId

Comment: Thank you!!! It works! Now if I may ask the only thing left is this: The highlighted selection stays on the previous rows I clicked though the id logs out only from the last row clicked as intended. How to remove the highlight from the previous row when I click a new one?

Comment: Maybe. With js or jquery in the click function, before set selected row, remove all selected rows (or only the previous one because you have store it). Try it and tell me :-)

Comment: thank You! What worked is the ``` if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        } ``` instead of the toggle line! Thank You for help!:)